# Display a list of all post from the Author in the author's page (author.php) in alphebetical order

Tags: author, order, list

wordpress noob here.

I'm trying to get a php code that will list all of the author's post in the author's page, or in author.php file, in alphabetical order. If anyone here knows how, please help.

Comment: `pre_get_posts`. There are a ton of resources on site. please feel free and use the site search. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

What Pieter Goosen said is exactly what you need to get this working.

[`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) is a very powerful function which is used to modify default behavior of main WordPress query. This hook is called after the query variable object is created, but before the actual query is run.

With `pre_get_posts` we will check for author query and change `order` and `orderby` parameters in it. This will make posts on author archive pages appear in alphabetical order instead of default post date.

```
function wpse_show_alphabetical_posts( $query ) {

    // no affect on admin or other queries
    if ( is_admin() || ! $query->is_main_query() )
        return;

    // if it's an author query
    if ( $query->is_author() ) {
        // change order and orderby parameters
        $query->set( 'orderby', 'title' );
        $query->set( 'order', 'ASC' );
    }

}
add_action( 'pre_get_posts', 'wpse_show_alphabetical_posts', 1 );
```

You should check [`pre_get_posts`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/pre_get_posts) documentation on codex for more information.

Comment: Did you try it? Is it working as you want?